# How to model an override in UML enumeration?

Tags: java, uml

What is the preferred way to model the below in a UML class diagram?

```
public enum myenum{
    VAL_A,
    VAL_B {
        @Override
        public String toString(){
            return "Value B";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suggestions would be

1) don't model toString in UML - it's an implementation detail which does not belong into the model

2) don't model methods of enum values, define a general contract for the enumeration instead

3) if you still want to do it define the enum value with an additional classifier (which can contain an operation) and add a dependency to the enum value

Comment: In this specific case I would simply add a comment which says "To represent a value in debug output the displayName should be used" and add a displayName attribute - or just name the constant accordingly and generate the implementation name

Comment: Hi @Christian ! Can implementation details be modeled using executable UML?

Comment: Of cause they _can_ be modeled. The question is, if you would like to model them or put them into the code generation (or model transformation) process instead.